# Deleting file issue

Tags: excel, vba, delete-file

My macro creates 1 identical txt files. One file is written to a shared network drive and the other file is written to a user personal drive.  The file names are identical.

Each file should have a Total Line.  Some files are created without a Total Line and this causes issues in downstream processing.  If we could isolate that issue, then this question is irrelevant.  However, we have not found the cause of the missing Total lines.

My solution was to check to check the shared network to see if the file exists. So far so good as that works.

Next I read the file (shared network drive) to see if the total line is found.  That works as expected.

If the total line isn't found, I want to use this code to delete both files:

```
Kill vFileName                       
Kill vFileName2
```

vFileName and vFileName2 contain the path and file name including extension.

When the code runs, the first "kill" command is executed as expected.

When the 2nd "kill" command is executed, the macro exits the subroutine, without deleting the file, and continues running.

I added a On Error GoTo 0 to see what the error message is but there is no error message.  I'm not sure what is going on.  Any suggestions as to what is going on and why the 2nd file is not deleted would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance for your help.......

Comment: Which file gets deleted and which file sticks around? I'm having trouble replicating the bug.

Comment: @cameroncritchlow.....the first file gets deleted and the 2nd file remains

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. Is the second file the file on the server, or on the user's drive. We can test if its related to the file location or the code by switching the kill file order. try killing vFileName2 first

Comment: The 2nd file is in the user's drive.  I'll switch them around and give that a try.  I wrote a little macro to delete a file from the user's drive and that worked fir me.  Just not 2 files one after the other.  Thanks for the help

Comment: The order of the kill-command shoudn't make a difference. Do you have an On Error-statement that hides an error? There should be a runtime error if the kill command fails.

Comment: @FunThomas...........I had put an On Error GoTo 0 statement right before the 2nd kill command to try and catch the error.  But that didn't seem to work.  When it tried to execute the 2nd kill command, the macro exits the subroutine and goes to the next line of code outside the subroutine....

Comment: I tried deleting 2 files in the users personal drive and that worked.  Do I need to change the drive / directory before deleting the second file?  Would a "wait" help

Even though the files are in different drives, the file name is identical.  Any chance that could be causing the issue?

Comment: This was user error.  I had closed the connection that created the first file but not the 2nd.  Once I closed the connection that created the 2nd file, I was able to delete the 2nd file.  Thanks for all of the help........